# Vim: Cucumber indentation for "And" lines

Tags: vim, cucumber

In Cucumber's Gherkin language, it's allowed to indent And lines, like so:

```
Scenario:
  Given there is a user named Chris
    And I am logged in as Chris
  When I go to the home page
  Then I should see "hi Chris"
    And I should not see "log in"
```

I like this indentation style much better than the equally-indented style, but with Tim's [Cucumber scripts for Vim](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2973), I have to manually indent the And lines and manually dedent the following lines, and sometimes Vim will automatically indent lines and it ends up all wrong.

What's the best way to work with indented And lines in Vim?  Or is it easiest to just give up on it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you could customize `indent/cucumber.vim` (online [here](https://github.com/tpope/vim-cucumber/blob/35b4a3ea17bab837540c7d371d3bd71b5d46eaf5/indent/cucumber.vim)) to increase the indent on lines starting with `^\s*And`.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a diff for `indent/cucumber.vim` based on Andy's answer:

```
--- .vim/indent/cucumber.vim.bak    2011-03-24 18:44:27.000000000 +0100
+++ .vim/indent/cucumber.vim    2011-03-24 19:09:41.000000000 +0100
@@ -47,6 +47,10 @@
     return indent(prevnonblank(v:lnum-1)) + &sw
   elseif cline =~# '^\s*[^|# \t]' && line =~# '^\s*|'
     return indent(prevnonblank(v:lnum-1)) - &sw
+  elseif cline =~# '^\s*\%(And\|But\)' && line !~# '^\s*\%(And\|But\)' 
+    return indent(prevnonblank(v:lnum-1)) + &sw
+  elseif cline !~# '^\s*\%(And\|But\)' && line =~# '^\s*\%(And\|But\)' 
+    return indent(prevnonblank(v:lnum-1)) - &sw
   elseif cline =~# '^\s*$' && line =~# '^\s*|'
     let in = indent(prevnonblank(v:lnum-1))
     return in == indent(v:lnum) ? in : in - &sw
```